# TortoiseHG and local unsync

Tags: eclipse, tortoisehg

There's a file in one of my patches that Tortoise thinks is there. I cannot import the patch MQ and remove the file because it keeps trying to find that file and gives the error: "Abort XXX.java no node!", or it says "no match found!". This file doesn't exist in my local, and I think this might have happened when my Eclipse had crashed.

How can I stop tortoise from thinking this file is still there? I can't seem to export this or do anything to remove it.

Comment: Did the file exist in Eclipse in the past? If so you might be able to restore it from Eclipse's local history.

Comment: yes it did exist, i'll see if i can try that

Comment: was able to restore it but it still didn't work. maybe it's because it added to my working directory as a new file, probably because it's a generated file